# How expensive are method calls in .net

Tags: .net

What is the relative performance cost of calling a method over in-line code?

Comment: What are you developing that you are so worried about the time consuming method call?

Comment: Relative? Probably an order of magnitude. But, don't let that fool you - (1/2,000,000,000)^10 is still a *really* small number.

Comment: Inlining usually trades space for time. If you're under memory pressure, your likely optimization would be to *not* inline. (Okay, really - your likely optimization would be to buy more RAM or distribute to more PCs with more RAM).

Comment: Don't forget that more memory means more cache misses, so even if you even if you're not under any memory pressure, this might differ. For this exact reason .NET 3.5 SP1 now inlines far less methods than previous versions of the framework.

Comment: In numbers, the cost of a method call in .NET is typically in the 10s-100s CPU-cycles.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That will depend on many things

- Whether the JIT inlines it for you
- Whether it's virtual
- The number and size of parameters
- Whether it's an instance method (with the implicit nullity check)
- Whether there's a return value (and its size if so)

It's very, *very* unlikely to be your bottleneck though. As always, write the most readable code you can first, and then benchmark it to see whether it performs well enough. If it doesn't, use a profiler to find the hotspots which *may* be worth micro-optimising.

Comment: in case of c# 2nd point is questionable. CSC emits `callvirt` for every method call

Comment: @Andrey: Using `callvirt` on non-virtual methods doesn't prevent the JIT to inline that method.

Comment: @Steven i didn't say it prevents inlining. I just told that virtual or not doesn't affect emitted instruction

Comment: @Andrey: Just because it's callvirt doesn't mean the JIT will actually resolve it virtually. If it spots that it's not a truly virtual method it won't need to use a vtable lookup.

Comment: From my experience, actually calling for the functions was bottleneck and when I used `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` the performance was greatly improved.

Comment: @googledev: While that *can* be the case, my experience is that it's very rare. But making sure you have a good set of performance tests and a profiler set up are the first steps towards working out whether it makes sense in any particular situation.

Answer (score 8):

There is a `cost` associated with method calls;

Arguments need to be pushed on the stack or stored in registers, the method prolog and epilog need to be executed and so on. The cost of these calls can be avoided by `In-lining.`

But, `JIT` uses a number of heuristics to decide whether a method should be in-lined. Following factors influence JIT, not to In-line a method.

- Methods that are greater than 32
  bytes of IL
- Virtual functions
- Methods that have complex flow
  control
- Methods that contain
  exception-handling blocks
- If any of the method's formal
  arguments are structs

Reference: [**Method Inlining**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973858.aspx#highperfmanagedapps_topic10)

Answer (score 3):

Same as in C++. Basically a call and a return, plus setting up parameters. Note, though, that the JIT can inline method calls - so it may not be as expensive in a particular context as you think.

Answer (score 2):

The performance cost is so inconsequential as to be irrelevant in comparison to making the code easy to read and its intent clear.

Comment: You can generally optimize for a subset of {speed, memory, reliability, programmer efficiency}.  I've found that if you optimize for programmer efficiency first, the others are fairly easy to do after.  Any other ordering doesn't work as well.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. If the intent of the code is easy to grasp by other programmer's, then performance efficiencies can be found later at a lower resource cost.

Answer (score 1):

Insignificant. Every call in .net, at least for C# is virtual call even if method is not marked virtual, consider it.

Comment: This doesn't mean that such is a virtual call. `callvirt` ensures the JIT adds a null check before calling any instance method. Still the JIT can choose to inline these methods when it sees they are not virtual.