# Is there any performance boost by using Lamda-expressions in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is any difference in the performance by doing the following:

```
        void Example(string message)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
```

or

```
        void Example(string message)
        {
            ConsoleMessage(message);
        }

        void ConsoleMessage(string message) => System.Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Comment: I am quite sure that line is inlined, if so it doesn't matter. If it *does* matter, #2 is slower. Not sure why you think it should be faster anyway.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it does not matter its the same at the end of the day

Comment: @DenisSchaf Can you show some proof?

Comment: Instead of asking strangers on the internet which horse is faster, race your horses. Performance is hard to predict so get in the habit of setting goals and measuring the performance of your code.

Comment: @DenisSchaf Not sure why you think that is actually OPs question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Both are the same It is never going to affect performance. The only purpose is to reduce lines of code

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, you probably need to mention who you're quoting ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can check how it compiles on [this website - SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnORVACxwCiAHgIYC2ADgDYCmAFEvM5wDOgxgHNOASjIUZpdDIWVEAOiQBObgOFjJaeYrgBfaeRMLqdJmy65eifkJHip+xXIMKCAewB2gr1wAso46miHOeh7G6GYyFt5+AZzB2uJ2DqmScAC8AHwIKuphmRKRFBiGQA==). As you can see

```
  void ConsoleMessage(string message) => System.Console.WriteLine(message);
```

is compiled to another method. The only difference is one more method call when using `Example2`. You can read more about cost of method calls in [this post - How expensive are method calls in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2463145/1319086)

> It's very, very unlikely to be your bottleneck though. As always, write the most readable code you can first, and then benchmark it to see whether it performs well enough. If it doesn't, use a profiler to find the hotspots which may be worth micro-optimising.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote that

```
    static void ConsoleMessage(string message) => Console.WriteLine(message);

    static void ExampleIndirect(string message)
    {
        ConsoleMessage(message);
    }

    static void ExampleDirect(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
```

By using JustDecompile on the release exe, I found that :

```
    private static void ConsoleMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private static void ExampleDirect(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private static void ExampleIndirect(string message)
    {
        Program.ConsoleMessage(message);
    }
```

So I'm not so sure that it "is compiled to another method".
However, the difference seems not to be noticeable on benchmarks.

EDIT :
Results of my benchmark :

```
Iterations / Direct Time (ms) / Indirect time (ms)
10      1       0
5000    154     148
50000   1514    1502
100000  3025    3019
500000  15191   15150
1000000 30362   30276
```

And the code :

```
    static void Loop(int times)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        writer.Write(times.ToString() + "\t");

        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            ExampleDirect("Test " + i.ToString());

        writer.Write(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + "\t");
        sw.Restart();

        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            ExampleIndirect("Test " + i.ToString());

        writer.Write(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Comment: You should post the benchmarks to support your assertion.